# How do I copy particular columns of one table to another table like we copy whole table by going in operations menu

Tags: mysql

How do I copy particular columns of one table to another table like we copy whole table by going in operations menu. But I have to only move particular columns how will I

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: My student tables have 11 columns but I have to move only 5 columns to another table. I don't know how to do it

Comment: What operations menu? What ide are you using? Do you mean column definitions or column definitions plus data? (plus indexes plus FKs etc)

Answer (score -1):

Use ALTER TABLE statement (to copy the column structures):
ALTER TABLE tbl_name ADD [COLUMN] (col_name column_definition,...)
Check out https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

Then use INSERT INTO SELECT statement (to import the data):
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
Check out https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - how does adding new colums move data between tables?

Comment: Well copying the structure of a column and importing data are completely different things. First you have to add the required columns to your table. Then you select the data you want to import to the other table and construct the INSERT statements using MySQL workbench or any other database tools (such as NetBeans). Your question doesn't clearly indicate that you want to import data from one table to another. You can also use INSERT INTO statement to insert the data from one table to another. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: Please add all explanation to your answer by editing